# Angular4 - Ag-grid - drop down custom list is not getting listed over the grid

Tags: angular, list, dropdown, ag-grid

I am using angular4 and created ag-grid with multiple custom drop down embedded inside it. when I click on the drop down, the respective drop down values are not appearing over the grid instead its increasing the grid size with scroll.

I am expecting the drop down list to appear over the grid.

To View the screen shot of an issue ==> [ag-grid-issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0Mnx.jpg)